# Python Selenium Set Multiple Chrome Preference

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to set multiple chrome options in my chrome browser. This is what I currently have:

```
prefs = {"download.default_directory" :  "Download/Path"}
moreprefs = {'safebrowsing.enabled': 'false'}
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", moreprefs)

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

The probblem is it only takes in to account the 1 of the chromeOptions.add_experimental and I need both

Answer (score 2):

update the prefs dictionary. and then set the preference.

```
prefs = {"download.default_directory" :  "Download/Path"}
moreprefs = {'safebrowsing.enabled': 'false'}
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

prefs.update(moreprefs)
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
prefs = {"download.default_directory": "your_dir", 'safebrowsing.enabled': True}

chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing. I'm sure the OP will find your input helpful, but please provide some explanation and context along with your answer to help other users understand it!